# How can I narrow a virtual kinect laser scan?

Tags: ros, kinect, laser, turtlebot, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am simulating a turtlebot in Gazebo, and currently I am having issues with the kinect laser scan, which sees about 270 degrees around the robot. I would like to narrow that so that the laser only picks up objects within the 90ish degrees directly in front of the bot. I haven't been able to find a parameter I can simply change to do this.

How might I go about narrowing the field of scan?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36439/how-can-i-narrow-a-virtual-kinect-laser-scan?/) by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest adjusting the parameters in the [pointcloud to laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan) node. You'll find it launched from turtlebot_gazebo/launch/robot.launch (in the simulated case) and turtlebot_bringup/kinect.launch (in the real-world case).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0